# Angular2: Using <select multiple> with ngControl not working?

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

It seems that it's not possible to use `ngControl` on a `select` input which accepts multiples values. `Control` value always returns a `string`.

Js:

```
this.selectControl = new Control([2, 3]);
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({'selectControl': this.selectControl});
```

Template:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm">
  <select ngControl="selectControl" size="5" multiple>
      <option *ngFor="#band of bands" [value]="band.value">{{ band.label }}</option> 
  </select><br>
  {{ selectControl.value | json}}
</form>
```

[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gpd2Je?p=preview) to experiment it.

Have you any idea or maybe this feature haven't been implemented yet.

PS: I'm using Angular2 beta13

Comment: why don't you use [`ng2-select`](http://valor-software.com/ng2-select/)?

Comment: yes that's an option but I prefer use native inputs when possible.

Comment: Because this is not native input. It does not look good on mobile devices.